# Excel macro to select and cut multiple rows to a new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I run a report every week and would like to cut the rows for a particular date range into a new worksheet (i.e. all rows with transactions between the 16th of one month to the 15th of the following month).

I'd like to cut all rows between 07/16 and 08/15 and past them in a new worksheet called "Aug"
And cut all rows between 08/16 and 09/15 and past them in a new workseet called "Sept"

**Example data**

Column A - Column B - Column C

Post Date - Name - Vendor

07/25/10 - Wilson - Starbucks

08/05/10 - Wilson - American Airlines

08/14/10 - Guang - Apple Store

08/15/10 - McGee - Staples

08/17/10 - Curry - AT&T

09/02/10 - Johnson - Exxon

09/11/10 - Simms - Old Navy

Comment: Do you want to cut them out - or just transfer them based on the date criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this will work if you have a header row on the destination sheet.  I just implemented the August copy and paste, but it would be simple to add September or make it completely generic and have it do the whole year.

```
Dim workingrow As Range

For Each workingrow In Sheets("Main").Rows

If (workingrow.Cells(1, 1).Value >= DateValue("7/16/2010")) And _ 
   (workingrow.Cells(1, 1).Value <= DateValue("8/15/2010")) Then
        workingrow.Copy (Sheets("Aug").Rows(1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))
End If

Next workingrow
```

Comment: Thanks for help.  I'm a beginner with VBA - i only use it for moving objects/editing graphs.

I think having a tab for each month would work.  With your above post I'm having trouble with the last command

workingrow.Copy (Sheets("Aug").Rows(1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))

I'm getting Application-defined error

Comment: @Sam, My guess would be that you're getting the error because the sheet is empty, which is why I said you needed to have a header row.  It needs at least one pre-existing row to work right (because of how the End method works).  To make it a __Cut__, just substitute Cut for Copy.