# Excel macro to copy rows to new sheet(s) based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

My query is below:

Each month my telecom provider gives me an excel list of all subscribers in the following format:

```
GSM number, account num, caller location, called location, units, cost

123456,     abc123456,   loc1,            loc2,            23,    11.231

123456,     abc123456,   loc8,            loc4,            5,     3

123456,     abc123456,   loc1,            loc4,            102,   71.1

789012,     def789012,   loc4,            loc5,            11,    1.43

789012,     def789012,   loc4,            loc5,            1,     0.23

345678,     ghi345678,   loc6,            loc7,            7,     2.23
```

and so on..

I'd want to go through the column A (gsm number) and copy all rows for that number to a worksheet named for the number, e.g. rows 1-3 would be copied to a worksheet named 123456.

I've managed to go though some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627939/create-macro-that-will-convert-excel-rows-from-single-sheet-to-new-sheets) [queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603911/excel-macro-to-select-and-cut-multiple-rows-to-a-new-worksheet) on this site and come up with something that works, but doesn't. The problems I'm facing is that the number of rows for a particular caller are not fixed (one row per call) and the number of callers are not fixed either (zero calls means no rows). I'm trying for a OnCellValueChange type solution - since I can understand & edit macros - but haven't written one yet.

Thanks for your time!

edit: also, as a side-note, can I also put a total of the "cost" column on each spreadsheet?

Edit Edit: Thanks to all for your solutions. However, my uncomfortability with VBA was hampering me. So, I'm just taking the excel sheet as-is in an SQL database and doing all of the formatting and querying in SQL/ASP directly online. So now users simply enter their phone # (and a password) and see their call records with dynamically generated subtotals and sortings. Thanks y'all for your very kind help.

Comment: please can you add your current attempted solution to the question

Comment: using array will help - fill an array with distinct `GSM number`s. Then loop through that array and for each value in the array create a worksheet and loop through all the rows in the spreadsheet looking for that number - if it is found then copy to the new sheet

Comment: `since I can understand & edit macros - but haven't written one yet.` If you can understand/edit macros why is this a problem? :-)  Please try your solution and identify problems - with the solution - rather than just hoping someone writes you an answer..

Comment: would you consider turning this into a pivot table? you can do reporting on each gsm by cost by grouping them.

Comment: I'm using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627939/create-macro-that-will-convert-excel-rows-from-single-sheet-to-new-sheets), but it is copying 3 rows for me only.

Comment: @enderland: I have very light javscript/html background hence I can see the VB code and make minor changes but can't go on writing a full fledged module yet.

Comment: @jospeh4tw: I have used the subtotal function. But all this goes on a website where each GSM user shall be seeing his/her data only. Hence the need for separate sheets or separate files which shall be password protected and available online.

Comment: @user1624085: Try this. Store the values from GSM into a Unique Collection. Then simply loop through the collection and use autofilter to get the rows of a selected number. Once you get that, simply copy the relevant visible rows to relevant sheet.

Answer (score 1):

As @joseph4tw says, you could do this with a pivot table similar to below (Excel 2010)...

- To show all item labels, choose: *Field Settings -> Layout & Print -> Repeat Item Labels*
- To create the sheet tabs just select *Pivot Table Options -> Show Report Filter Pages* (as below)

[image]

[image]

**Update** Having created the sheet tabs, you can use group editing to format as required...

- select all the tabs by shift-clicking the last tab,
- select the whole sheet and paste special values to remove all pivot tables
- delete the first two rows and autosize columns as shown

[image]

Comment: Hi,Thanks to all for your solutions. However, my uncomfortability with VBA was hampering me. So, I'm just taking the excel sheet as-is in an SQL database and doing all of the formatting and querying in SQL/ASP directly online. So now users simply enter their phone # (and a password) and see their call records with dynamically generated subtotals and sortings. Thanks y'all for your very kind help.