# Filtering to new sheets from master sheet in Excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel, populate

Im wondering if this is possible with excel.  I have a list of employees with multiple columns counting up their production in my company.  It is a list of about 40 names and has about 10 columns of different tasks that are counted up to determine productivity.  these people are split up into different teams and i have their names tagged with the team. For example, if joe smith was in customer service, his name says CSR-Joe Smith.  I want to be able to use this excel sheet over and over again so i can simply run this master report and put the data into one sheet to populate a different sheet for each team.  Is there a way to do this by looking at the team tag i add to each persons name and extract from the list of employees the team members that are on the same team? Im working on excel 2010 and have some knowledge of VB and C coding in excel but not a ton of experience with it. I also want to pull the values for each team member in each column.

here is an example if my words didnt make sense, each employee has a row like this.

```
name          status1   status 2    status 3    status 4    status 5
CSR-Joe Smith   251       358          12          58           9
```

I should mention that this data is gathered from a SQL query that i want to pull out of MS SQL management studio and am copying into excel.

Comment: this question was kind of hard to word for me so if you need more info please ask.

Comment: Why don't you connect a query (through Excel data connection) for each data sheet that represents each team. So you filter each SQL statement on `[name] LIKE "CSR*"` for each team and run those SQL's against a new data sheet each. Alternatively, you could dump the whole SQL return into one spreadsheet and use a small amount of VBA to dump each team on a new sheet.

Comment: i could probably figure out the SQL idea, can you direct me to the right place in excel to get started with that? or maybe somewhere online for some guidance? not sure i can figure out the VBA yet, i can set up macros and whatnot but only when the code is given to me really.  I can read it though, just no experience writing it really.

Comment: You might be able to set up a Pivot Table and use the Show Pages command to output new sheets for each team similar to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119660/excel-macro-to-copy-rows-to-new-sheets-based-on-column-value/12129393#12129393

Comment: thanks for the help but i dont think thats exactly what i need, i have all the results i need in 1 row per employee already, im trying to split up that info into seperate sheets.

Comment: `i could probably figure out the SQL idea, can you direct me to the right place in excel to get started with that? ` In the Excel Ribbon, go to `Data` > `From Other Sources` > `From SQL Server`. That will require no VBA at all -> which is probably better!

Comment: I am with Scott on the point that this should be solved on the SQL-side, because it is a typicall database-problem. But however, as you asked for excel, there might be attempts with pivotTable, subsum, vlookup or vba - question is, if and what is necessary. Please explain your question further - having real trouble understanding this:  _I want to be able to use this excel sheet over and over again so i can simply run this master report and put the data into one sheet to populate a different sheet for each team._

Comment: after playing with this for a while i think you are right on the SQL, i have tried to create a macro to run multiple queries and then put the data into each sheet.  all i needed to do was create custom queries for each team i wanted to split up, my only issue now is that my query is way too long to fit into a macro so i have to go back a few steps and see what i can do.  to clarify for you @jook i want to basically have a dump of my data into one sheet and to have a pre set up workbook with multiple sheets that will pull data from that data dump based on their team names.

Comment: i do have the ability to add another column to seperate the CSR part away from the joe smith part so there are two columns for that instead of 1 if that is needed

Comment: _my query is way too long to fit into a macro_ oO With _on the SQL-side_ I ment, on the SQL-serverside - not in your vba-macro. Your server should provide a view, which you are able to access with few modifications to get to your data. You can then even use an exported-connection-file for each group, which excel can open directly.

Comment: @Jook ahhh! i didnt think of that! totally forgot i could do that, ill see if that gets me anywhere and ill check back in a bit, at work now and have to move to another project for the time being but will be back on this later today, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To sum it up, my solution for this kind of problem and related:

Solve database-problems in a database, whenever you can ;)

It is far more easy to make joins, selection and filtering inside a database, than inside excel.

If you have to do it in excel, see if **subsum**, **pivotTable** or **vlookup** can help you, because those could most likely do.

Be alarmed, when you start trying to solve database-problems with vba - usually there are better ways, or at least there should be. When you have a good datasource - like sql - it should definetly be your first attempt to get create a better view or table in sql.

Additionlly, you can use **.odc** connection-files with excel directly. By opening one, you create a new Workbook and you will open your connection as a worksheet.