# copy designate rows and columns to a new worrkbook with an autosum function included

Tags: excel, vba

First I have to say that i have absolut no glue of programming. I even not understand how to do here an text looks like an Excel list. Sorry for that. 
My problem is that i have to insert the phonebills of every member of our company into an Access- Database and spread out also the excle files to each member.
I got every week an excel worksheet called vodafone AUG_12 (Vodafone actual month_year) with over 50000 rows and several columns in it. The 1st column contains several phonenumbes, the last column (I) contains the costs for each dial from the number in the first column.
For example:

```
PhoneNu      Date       Time       Int. Code   City Code   Destination  Description  Duration  Costs 

123456789    20120829   08:15:00   0049        431         12456        Kiel         00:02:15  02.95
123456789    20120829   08:17:00   0049        431         12456        Kiel         00:19.95  17.45
234567890    20120829   09:15:22   0031        21          5632145      Lisbon       00:00:28   0.10
234567890    20120829   17:25:00   0031        21          5632145      Lisbon       00:00:59   0.28
345678901    20120829   00:13:31   00351       91          5896         Service      00:03:45   2.58
345678901    20120829   06:45:13   00351       91          5896         Service      01:25:13  12.85
```

etc.

Is there a way to copy the rows for each number in a new workbook which has the name of the number, put also the sum of the costs in it and save it in the same folder as the original.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever is interested in it, you can see my solution below. That runs for my data file around 20 min.
It took time to come to this result. With recherging copied macros and recording/adapt them.

```
Sub delete_0()
    'change directory
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "G:\01_Phone_Bills\extbills\v_201212\Vodafone_Dec_12.csv" 

   'delete all rows which contains 0 in column 15 in the original invoice
   Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
  If Cells(i, 15) = "0" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'startthe next macros
 Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!delete_member_PhoneNumbers"
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!delete_Tx_Easy_Roaming"
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!Make_it_readable"
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!renamesheet"
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!delete_non_user_phone_numbers"
 ChDir "G:\01_Phone_Bills\extbills\v_201212"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    "G:\01_Phone_Bills\extbills\v_201212\Vodafone_Dec_12.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!Autosum_insert"
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!copy_amount"
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!delete_Bill_summery_0"
Application.Run "'make it readable.xlsm'!MakeMultipleXLSfromWB"
End Sub



Sub delete_member_PhoneNumbers()

 'delete all rows which contains phone number ... in column 10
 'in the original invoice, user have not to pay for that calls 

Dim a As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For a = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
  If Cells(a, 10) = "123456789" Then Rows(a).Delete
 Next a
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True


 End Sub

 Sub delete_Tx_Easy_Roaming()

'delete all rows which contains Tx Easy Roaming in column 11
'in the original invoice, user have not to pay for that fee     

Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
  If Cells(i, 11) = "Tx Easy Roaming" Then Rows(i).Delete
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



 Sub Make_it_readable()
 '
 ' Convert the original invoice into a readable excel format

 ' Replace all file names

 '

 Rows("1:3").Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 Cells.Select
 Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
 Columns("A:A").Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
 Columns("B:D").Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
 Columns("I:J").Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
 Columns("I:I").Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
 Columns("J:L").Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
 Range("A1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "PhoneNu"
 Range("B1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
 Range("C1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Time"
 Range("D1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Country Code"
 Range("E1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "City Code"
 Range("F1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Destination"
 Columns("F:F").Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
 Range("G1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Description"
 Range("H1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Duration"
 Range("I1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Cost"
 Range("J1").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total amount"
 Cells.Select
 Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
 Cells.Select
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Vodafone_Dec_12").Sort.SortFields.Clear 'replace "Voda..."
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Vodafone_Dec_12").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A50000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
 With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Vodafone_Dec_12").Sort 'replace "Voda..."
    .SetRange Range("A1:R50000")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
 End With
 Columns("A:A").Select
 Selection.NumberFormat = "## #######"
 ActiveSheet.Name = "Bill Summery"

  'create the number of sheets which you need
    Dim lnumber As String
    Dim i As Long
     Anf:
    lnumber = InputBox("How often should the macro run ?", , 3)

     'check the input for a figure
   If IsNumeric(lAnzahl) Then
    For i = 1 To CLng(lnumber)
        Range("A:A:J:J").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Paste

     Next i
  Else
     MsgBox "Please enter a figure !", vbInformation
    GoTo Anf
End If


End Sub

Sub renamesheet()
'
' renames each sheet
'

 '

Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Tel 123456789"
Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "Tel 234567890"
Sheets("Sheet3").Name = "Tel 345678901"


Public Sub delete_non_user_phone_numbers()

'delte all pfone numbers without that from the user

'Sheet activation
 Sheets("Tel 123456789").Select
 'find last row
 lz = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows.Row
 'check all rows
 For t = lz To 2 Step -1 'count back to row 2
 'check if ther is "..."in the first column
 If Not Cells(t, 1).Value = "123456789" Then
    Rows(t).Delete Shift:=xlUp
  End If
 Next t
 'Sheet activation
 Sheets("Tel 234567890").Select
      lz = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows.Row
 For t = lz To 2 Step -1 
 If Not Cells(t, 1).Value = "234567890" Then
    Rows(t).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
 Next t
'Sheet activation
 Sheets("Tel 345678901").Select
 lz = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows.Row
 For t = lz To 2 Step -1 
 If Not Cells(t, 1).Value = "345678901" Then
    Rows(t).Delete Shift:=xlUp
 End If
 Next t


  Sub Autosum_insert()

'do the autosum in each sheet column I and fill it in J2

ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlFirst
Sheets("Bill Summery").Select
Columns("A:J").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Position:=xlLast
Sheets(Array("Bill Summery", "Tel 123456789", "Tel 234567890", "Tel 345678901")).Select
Sheets("Bill Summery").Activate

Dim intI As Integer
For intI = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-1]:R[1111]C[-1])"

Next intI
End Sub



 Sub copy_amount()
 '
 ' copy_amount Macro
 '
 'copy A1 and J2 from every sheet in Bill Summery
 '
 Sheets("Tel 123456789").Select
 Range("J2,A2").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Bill Summery").Select
 Range("A1:B1").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 Sheets("Tel 234567890").Select
 Range("J2,A2").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Bill Summery").Select
 Range("A2:B2").Select

 ActiveSheet.Paste
 Sheets("Tel 345678901").Select
 Range("J2,A2").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("Bill Summery").Select
 Range("A3:B3").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 End Sub

 Sub delete_Bill_summery_0()

 'delete all rows in sheet Bill summery which have a 0 printed in column2

 Sheets("Bill Summery").Select
 Dim i As Long
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
  If Cells(i, 2) = "0" Then Rows(i).Delete
  Next i
 End Sub


 Option Explicit

 Sub MakeMultipleXLSfromWB()



 'Split worksheets in current workbook into
 ' many separate workbooks  D.McRitchie, 2004-06-12
 'Close each module  AND the VBE before running to save time
 ' provides a means of seeing how big sheets really are
 'Hyperlinks and formulas pointing to other worksheets within
 ' the original workbook will usually be unuseable in the new workbooks.
  Dim CurWkbook As Workbook
 Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
 Dim newWkbook As Workbook
 Dim wkSheetName As String
 Dim shtcnt(3) As Long
 Dim xpathname As String, dtimestamp As String
 dtimestamp = Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss")
 'change the directory
 xpathname = "G:\01_Phone_Bills\extbills\v_201212\D" & dtimestamp & "\"
 MkDir xpathname
 Set CurWkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

 shtcnt(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 For Each wkSheet In CurWkbook.Worksheets
  shtcnt(1) = shtcnt(1) + 1
  Application.StatusBar = shtcnt(1) & "/" & shtcnt(2) & _
      "  " & wkSheet.Name
  wkSheetName = Trim(wkSheet.Name)
  If wkSheetName = Left(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name, _
     Len(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4) Then _
     wkSheetName = wkSheetName & "_D" & dtimestamp
  Workbooks.Add
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
     Filename:=xpathname & wkSheetName & ".xls", _
     FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", _
     WriteResPassword:="", CreateBackup:=False, _
     ReadOnlyRecommended:=False
  Set newWkbook = ActiveWorkbook

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  newWkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Delete
  On Error Resume Next
  newWkbook.Worksheets(wkSheet.Name).Delete
  On Error GoTo 0
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  CurWkbook.Worksheets(wkSheet.Name).Copy Before:=newWkbook.Sheets(1)
  'no duplicate sheet1 because they begin with "a"
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
 Next wkSheet
 Application.StatusBar = False      'return control to Excel
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to split this 50000 records on the individual no and then for each unique no to have a worksheet / workbook that would contain all of the details and then compute the costs?

if yes

--> to make it faster I would use c# and link to excel through ado, but you said that programming is not your sweet point :D

--> use vba (it will take some time to complete) make a loop to go through the lines and then simply copy the entire row over to a new worksheet that has the name of the phone no.; after you are done with the loop go through the worksheets and set the sum: get the last cell below the costs and use setformula to put sum.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am able to record a Macro. But in the next month file I have than a different count of rows for each number so that I can not use the recorded Macro. May I am only to stupid, but I am not understanding the programm code of the VBA, I tried some examples from different internet pages and also get information from VBA hand books, however I am not understanding the way it works.

Comment: yes, it is normal that the no of rows change.
you do a 
    For i = 1 to Sheet1.UsedRange.Row
    do some copying around
    next i

Comment: generally you record more macros to do exactly what you need, then just start modifying one of the macros already there and when you will activate it, it will run the same. My advice is to start with 10 rows, then do a loop through these 10 rows and copy them to their worksheets

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119660/excel-macro-to-copy-rows-to-new-sheets-based-on-column-value?rq=1
it is very similar to what you need

Comment: Thanks for your support. Therfore i am no knowing what a loop is or how i could use the "for next". I think I will buy some books and try to come into VBA programming.