# If column has word FAIL copy row to failed sheet (also allow multiple keywords)

Tags: excel

Ok lets see if I can make this as easy to understand as possible.  I'm working on an inspection workbook.  This book is composed of many sheets each with its own name.  I have been working with a few people to figure out ways to flag and copy "BLANKornovalue" cells but can not get the keyword idea to work.

Here is a short example of a sheet.
    Name = Initiating devices

```
`$`Column A = adrress
`$`Column B = Type
`$`Column C = location
`$`Column D = Part#
`$`Column E = (RESULTS)  dropdown choices
```

The only column I'm looking at at the moment is "E" "Results"  Results can have many different choices from a drop down box,  (FAIL, DAMAGED, LOW VOLTS, LOW AMPS, ets)  I'm adding to it as i get feedback before the final copy.  When an inspector clicks on the dropdown box and selects the words listed above that row would then be copied to the first available space on "FAILED" sheet.  First available space would be A6 (due to a title graphic)

Then if the repairs are made the inspector or service tech would be able to change column "E" on the "FAILED" sheets page to another dropdown box.  It would have choices like (PASS, REPLACED, REPAIRED, etc)  When that was selected the same device and column in the "INITIATING DEVICES" would be updated and the item would be removed from the "FAILED" sheet all items would shift up leaving no spaces.  This should happen after the device has been selected if possible.

I'm hoping that once i get a working example I will be able to adapt the code to work with several sheets, so that different values would place the items on different sheets.  But that is yet to come.

Example 
Column 6 (RESULTS) keyword = FAIL, or Fail or fail or Damaged, or low volts, or low amps, would copy all rows with this value to "FAIL" sheet

keyword = message change copy the row to a sheet called "Message changes" etc

Any help would be great and thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need Excel. You need an Access database. Adding all this programmatic decoration to move things around in Excel is *possible*, but I emphatically advise against it.

Comment: You can use pivot too. instead of copy stuff. look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119660/excel-macro-to-copy-rows-to-new-sheets-based-on-column-value?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. Its simple really if you know a little VBA. But I concur with ErikE that you should use Access or somthing similar

```
            Option Compare Text
            Option Explicit

            Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
                Dim rng As Range
                Dim row As Long
                Dim newRowId As Long

                If ActiveSheet.Name = "Blad1" Then

                    For Each rng In Target.Cells
                        Select Case rng.Value
                            Case "FAIL"
                                row = rng.row
                                Rows(row).Cut
                                newRowId = findFirstAvailableRow(8, 1, "Blad2")
                                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Blad2").Rows(newRowId).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                            Case Else

                        End Select
                    Next
                End If
            End Sub
            Private Function findFirstAvailableRow(iStartIndex As Long, SearchColumnIndex As Long, workSheetName As String) As Integer
                Dim i As Long

                For i = iStartIndex To 32000
                    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(workSheetName).Cells(i, SearchColumnIndex).Value = "" Then
                        findFirstAvailableRow = i
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End Function
```

Just copy it into your sheet and change the sheet names (I've got the swedish version and EVERY bloody thing is regionalized in Excel)

Comment: thankyou I will give this a try and see what all happens, i got it to work using some other things but it doesnt restore.  I will get back to you and thanks again for the help

Comment: Ok i just tried copying your code into the worksheet "INITIATING DEVICES" and changed the names to work. I see that the function works automatically as i needed but im also seeing that the device that is listed is removed from the "INITIATING DEVICES" worksheet and pasted into the the "FAILED"  worksheet.  I'm wondering if its possible to copy it and still leave it on the "INITIATING DEVICES" sheet as well, and then if the status is later changed to "PASS, REPLACED, or some other value that I can choose" it would be removed from the "FAILED" sheet and the results column "E" would be updated.

Comment: I wish i knew how to get around the limit on this comments page sorry.  Also would it be possible to add more then one word where it says Case = "FAIL" could if change it to Case = "FAIL" or Case = "DAMAGED" etc.  I can send a copy of the inspection if needed.  I would love to use another program but our company does not wish to allow inspectors to have access on the computer, and i have never worked with it at all.  Thanks again for the hlep.  Bill

Comment: You can add as many as you wish in the case "Fail" and just change Rows(row).Cut to Rows(row).Copy. To be able to change the status back you need to store the row number in a column in the new sheet, or have a unique key in the orginal row so you can search back for the row.